# wxSplashScreen Blank

Tags: wxpython

I have a wx application which I just added a splash screen to, the problem is that sometimes (about 10% of the time) the splash screen frame pops up but is blank.  I wrote the following test, which replicates the problem (below).  The wx.Yield() helped somewhat, as the fail rate was more like 50% without it.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import wx

SLEEP_TIME = 1.0 # seconds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    splash_image = wx.Image('spikepy_splash.bmp').ConvertToBitmap()

    splash_screen = wx.SplashScreen(splash_image, 
            wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN|wx.SPLASH_NO_TIMEOUT, 0, None)
    wx.Yield()
    #wx.SafeYield()
    #wx.GetApp().Yield()
    wx.Sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
```

Comment: What platform? It works for me.

Comment: BTW, you can just use wx.Bitmap('spikepy_splash.bmp')

Comment: And what's supposed to happen after the code shown? Generally you create the splash screen, load everything and show your main window, and then destroy the splash screen and finally enter app.MainLoop().

Comment: @ FogleBird: I can replicate the problem on Ubuntu 9.04, python 2.6, wxPython 2.8.9.1.  The problem appears to not exist on my mac 10.6 with python 2.6 and wxPython 2.8.10.1.  Also changing to wx.Bitmap does not affect the issue.

Comment: @David Morton: The wx.Bitmap thing was just an unrelated tip.

Comment: Does the wxPython demo's splashscreen work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be important to keep from doing anything before app.MainLoop().  To get around this limitation just use wx.CallLater or similar. That way you add what you wanted to do before the MainLoop() to the event stack so that it happens after the call to MainLoop().

This resolved the issue for me, both in the below test code and the main application I'm writing.  I just added all my imports and gui construction to a function and then used wx.CallLater to run that function.

```
import wx

SLEEP_TIME = 1.0 # seconds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    splash_image = wx.Image('spikepy_splash.bmp').ConvertToBitmap()

    splash_screen = wx.SplashScreen(splash_image, 
            wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN|wx.SPLASH_NO_TIMEOUT, 0, None)

    wx.CallLater(1000*SLEEP_TIME, splash_screen.Destroy)
    app.MainLoop()
```